# C# Remove Event Handler after is called or call it just once

Tags: c#, events

```
_cefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd += (s, e) =>
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         MyCefStringVisitor visitor = new MyCefStringVisitor(this, m_url);
         e.Browser.GetMainFrame().GetSource(visitor);
         loaded = true;
    }));
};
```

But problem is that Event Handler is called many times. After each JS reload for example. How to remove multiple calls. How to call `LoadEnd` event just once.

I try with

```
_cefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd -= delegate { };
```

but not working.

What can i do? I want to call it just once!

Comment: Try assigning the method to an EventHandler object. Then assign and unassign the object.

Comment: Have you tried using a normal method instead of an anonymous (s,e)=>{...} which you can then reference in .LoadEnd-=MyMethod?

Comment: how do you mean normal method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method

```
public void Browser_LoadEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         MyCefStringVisitor visitor = new MyCefStringVisitor(this, m_url);
         _cefGlueBrowser.Browser.GetMainFrame().GetSource(visitor);
         loaded = true;
    }));
}
```

subscribe

```
_cefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd += Browser_LoadEnd;
```

and unsubscribe

```
_cefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd -= Browser_LoadEnd;
```

Note, I assume that the `LoadEnd` event takes `EventArgs` and not some derived class.

Answer (score 53):

```
EventHandler handler = null;
obj.SomeEvent += handler = (s, e) => {
    obj.SomeEvent -= handler;
    // more stuff
};
```

This works because it is the variable that us captured (lexical closure), not the value of the variable at any particular time.

Comment: Is there a generic version for this?

Comment: just to know: this method does not assure the event handler is called just one time; if there are two thread from there the event is fired at the same time, the handler is called twice.

Comment: To add to this, if you are using `Action` or `Action<>` or `Func<>` you can use them as handlers as well.
`Action handler = null; (...)`

Answer (score 3):

Define the event handler in a separate method and add the unsubscribing operation to its method body:

```
public EventHandler OnLoadEnd(object sender, <args>)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        MyCefStringVisitor visitor = new MyCefStringVisitor(this, m_url);
                        _cefGlueBrowser.Browser.GetMainFrame().GetSource(visitor);
                        loaded = true;
                    }));

    _cefGlueBrowser.LoadEnd -= OnLoadEnd;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you! Please consider marking my answer as - well - answer.

Comment: Wanted to know if c# can cope with unregistering the function that was invoked inside itself. This seems to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mark Gravel response, I think you need also at least a flag

```
        bool done = false;
        EventHandler eh = null;
        obj.evt += eh = (_, e) => {
            obj.evt -= eh;
            if (done)
                return;
            done = true;

            // stuff
        };
```

Comment: If it's threading you're worried about, you should probably use a lock rather than a flag.  It's possible for each thread to get past the if(done) at the same time.